# Seleccionar el value de un select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola que tal a todos tengo una duda con respecto a un select, pasa que quiero que uno de los values de ellos ejemplo:

```
<select  id="test">
                <option value="100" selected>Precio1</option>
               <option value="200" selected>Precio2</option>
            </select>
```

Pasa que esto es una list para mandar los datos en un form de paypal y tengo lo siguiente

```
$pp = array( 
    'cmd' => '_xclick', 
    'cert_id' => $cert_id, 
    'business' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',                 
    'receiver_email' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',                 
    'custom' => '1',          
    'item_name' => **>>Justo acá quiero que me aparezca el "value" osea en la option 1 que me salga 100 <<** ,                  
     'currency_code' => 'USD',                            
    'amount' => '1',                                     
   .....................
);
```

Pues estuve intentado con javascript con un onclick en el form y agregando un post en item_name ejemplo $_POST['test'],

mientras el code javascript que intente era este

```
function mostrarValue(){

    var selObj = document.getElementById('test');
       var selIndex = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Espero y alguien pueda guiarme en esto se los agradecería mucho, saludos y gracias de ante mano.

Este es el código en sí que estoy usando.

```
   <script language="javascript"> 
function mostrarValue(){

    var selObj = document.getElementById('test');
       var selIndex = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

    }
</script> 
<p>Seleccione uno de los articulos</p>
        <label class="youplay-select">
                <select  id="test" name="test">
                <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
                <option value="1000">Articulo1</option>
                <option value="1001">Articulo2</option>
                <option value="1002">Articulo3</option>

            </select>
        </label>


<?php
$cert_id = 'CERTIFICADOPAYPAL'; 
include("Class.PayPalEWP.php"); 
$paypal = new PayPalEWP(); 
$paypal->setTempFileDirectory("tmp");
$paypal->setCertificate("my-pubcert.pem", "my-prvkey.pem"); 
$paypal->setPayPalCertificate("paypal_cert_pem.txt"); 
$paypal->setCertificateID($cert_id);  

$pp = array( 
        'cmd' => '_xclick', 
        'cert_id' => $cert_id, 
        'business' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',                 
        'receiver_email' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',                 
        'custom' => '1',         
        'item_name' $_POST['test'],                  
         'currency_code' => 'USD',                             
        'amount' => '1',                                   
        'lc' => 'ES',                                         
        'no_note' => '1',                                     
        'no_shipping' => '1',                                  
        //'return' => '',                     
        'cancel_return' => '',             
        //'notify_url' => '',               
        'cbt' => 'Volver al sitio web', 


    );

?> 


  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  id="pay_pal_form" method="POST" name= "form1" onclick="mostrarValue();">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----<?php echo $paypal->encryptButton($pp); ?>-----END PKCS7-----"/> 

  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma más segura y rápida de pagar en línea."> 
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></p></div>
</form>
```

Quiero que este me envíe el value del "item_name" para así en el ipn insertarlo en una db, pero de las formas que he intentado me guarda lo que es "Precio1" y no "100"  y con el metodo que resalto en mi codigo al enviar el formulario me pide que introduzca un nuevo nombre, toma como si no tuviera item_name alguno

Comment: En tu ejemplo no veo que tu elemento <select> tenga su atributo name, si cuentas ya con el código que estás usando para hacer lo que quieres hacer, inclúyelo de tal forma que se pueda representar el error.

Comment: @Yikarus que tal ya lo he añadido completo si puedes ayudarme te agradecería

Comment: el select tienes que crearlo dentro de otro formulario, para que el usuario seleccione la opción.. después preguntar si se recibio ese dato asignarlo a tu item_name

Answer (score 1):

Podría utilizar Jquery, de esta manera obtener el valor del select seria muy facil, un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select  id="test">
<option value="100" selected>Precio1</option>
<option value="200" selected>Precio2</option>
</select>

<button onclick="mostrarValue()">
Mostrar valor
</button>

<script>
function mostrarValue(){
alert("Valor de #test: "+$("#test").val())
}
</script>
```

saludos

Comment: Que tal Yeison, he intentado con tú método pero tampoco me da lo que quiero hacer, he dejado el código completo y una breve explicacion de lo que deseo hacer, espero y puedas ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo para hacerlo con `$_POST`,  fíjate que he cambiado el atributo `id` que tienes en el form por el atributo `name`. Ya que lo que envías en el formulario es el atributo `name` y el atributo `value`.

```
/* formulario.html */
<form method="post" action="proceso.php">
  <select name="test">
    <option value="A">Artículo A</option>
    <option value="B">Artículo B</option>
   </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit del form"/>
</form>
/*En el fichero proceso.php*/
    if(isset($_POST['test'])) 
        echo $_POST['test']; // Sacas el valor
```

Answer (score 1):

si entendí bien tu solo quieres obtener el valor del select seleccionado para poder enviar una petición ?

Eso lo logras obteniendo el valor value del elemento. Por ejemplo:

```js
let obtenerValor = function(e){
  let select = document.querySelector('#auto');
  console.log(select.value)
}
```

```html
<select name="auto" id="auto">
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>

<button onclick="obtenerValor()">Obtener Valor</button>
```

Espero que haya sido de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Que tal Facundo, primeramente  gracias por la ayuda, lo que busco es hacerle un llamado a el valor para así asignarlo a el item_name del formulario paypal, he intentado con tú script, pero no funciona  he realizado lo siguiente
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal." onclick="obtenerValor()"> 

Mientras que en el array del paypal lo he dejado así 
'item_name' => $_POST['auto'],
y nada que me envía el value como item name de paypal u.ú.
Saludos y gracias por la ayuda.